# pseudocode to Put Even & Odd Elements of an Array in 2 Separate Arrays

Tags: java

Write pseudocode to Put Even & Odd Elements of an Array in 2 Separate Arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InsertElementInArray 

    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int n, pos, x;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
            n = s.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n+1];
            System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i] = s.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the position where you want to insert element:");
            pos = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the element you want to insert:");
            x = s.nextInt();
            for(int i = (n-1); i >= (pos-1); i--)
            {
                a[i+1] = a[i];
            }
            a[pos-1] = x;
            System.out.print("After inserting:");
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i]+",");
            }
            System.out.print(a[n]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: This is Q&A site, not T&I (Task and Implementation). Of course we can provide some code for you, but only the essential parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code and pseudocode both are heading in same way, but the main difference is the second one is much easier to write and understand for humans.
Let's take an example: We have a function that takes an string array as an argument and performs some complicated operations like searching for some specified char chains or looking for a pattern with regex.
It can looks very simply in pseudocode:

```
function doLotsOfStuff(String array):
    variable patternApperance
    for each string in array:
        if (string has "PATTERN"):
            increment patternApperance
    return patternApperance
```

The thing about pseudocode is that it doesn't have any specific way or convention of writing. It's something where you don't have to care if it is going to compile, parse etc. but only care about that if others understand your pseudocode. In short words pseudocode isnt made for computers, it's for humans to better understand what a piece of code is going to do.